# Can I buy alcohol in duty free in Belgium and take it in my carry-on luggage through TSA check in Dublin?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, tsa, duty-free, pre-clearance

I'm soon taking a flight from Brussels to San Francisco with Aer Lingus via the US preclearance in Dublin. I have read elsewhere that it's ok to buy alcohol in duty free shops in Dublin if they are in a sealed bag and then take them in my carry-on luggage through the TSA check in Dublin. Does anyone know if the same holds for alcohol bought elsewhere in Europe?

I find the [TSA website](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/liquids-rule) a bit confusing as it states that this rule only holds if one travels "to the United States with a connecting flight."

Comment: AFAIK pre check in Dublin concerns customs and immigration. There is no TSA there. Coming from Brussels you’ll probably won’t need to go through security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your duty-free item is in a sealed red-bordered bag, then it will pass through security at Dublin pre-clearance with no problems.

[image: Duty-free shopping bag]

Where you might have a problem is if you have a connecting flight after you land in the US. If you have to go through security again, which may be the case at some airports, TSA will not accept this, (my understanding is that they ought to, but don't in practice, but it's been quite a while since I looked deeply into it) and since you have been through preclearance you won't have an opportunity to access your checked bags as you would have if you cleared customs in the US.

Comment: San Francisco is my final destination, so there should be no problem!